# Construction of Reals Extended to Cesaro Sequences

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

The real numbers can be [constructed](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/resource/general/131ah.1.03w/week2.pdf) as the [set of Cauchy sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction_of_the_real_numbers#Construction_from_Cauchy_sequences) (e.g. 3, 3.1, 3.14, 3.141, 3.1415,...) under the equivalence relation that their difference tends to 0.

- Real numbers are equivalence classes of real number sequences, $a = (a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots)$
- These sequences must be Cauchy:

  - you give me an $\epsilon > 0$
  - I can give you can $N > 0$ such that
  - if you give me any $n > N $
  - we have $|a_n - a_m| < \epsilon$
- Equivalence relation: $a \equiv b$ if for any $\epsilon > 0$ , there exist $N > 0$ with $|a_n - b_n|< \epsilon$ for all $n > N$.

Then we have to check these have the properties of the real numbers we like: $(a+b)+c = a + (b+c)$, [least upper bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_upper_bound_axiom) property, etc.

Oh, I tried writing the definition of Cauchy sequence as a "game".  Any leads on that are welcome in the comments.

---

I had been reading about the divergent sequences [1 - 2 + 3 - 4 + ...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%25E2%2588%2592_2_%252B_3_%25E2%2588%2592_4_%252B_%25C2%25B7_%25C2%25B7_%25C2%25B7) and how to add them.  The partial sums are 1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, ... which diverge.  We can try averaging the partial sums get 1, 0, 2/3, 0, 3/5, 0, 5/7, 0,... which still doesn't converge

Maybe instead use the simpler example [1 -1 + 1 -1+...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandi%2527s_series) whose partial sums are 1,0,1,0,1,0 and we "claim" the sum should be "$\frac{1}{2}$".  This is the [Cesaro sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%25C3%25A0ro_summation) of the alternating sequence.  What's iffy is that we can rearrange the sequence to -1+1-1+1-... which should tend to  $-\frac{1}{2}$.  But that rearrangement is "infinite" in some sense.

I would like to know about the collection infinite sequences of (say) rational numbers admitting [Cesaro averages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%25C3%25A0ro_mean).  We could say $a \equiv b$ if $a_n - b_n$ has Cesaro mean tending to $0$, I think this is another construction of the real numbers.

**What if we just ask $a_n - b_n$ be Cauchy? What is the set of equivalence classes of rational numbers with Cesaro averages modulo the Cauchy sequences.**  It's probably not even Hausdorff.

---

Loosely related, there is a construction of the reals due to [A'Campo](http://www.math.ethz.ch/~salamon/PREPRINTS/acampo-real.pdf) of real numbers as "slopes" or "almost homomorphisms".

- A "slope" is a sequence of number $ \lambda: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ with $\{ \lambda(m)+\lambda(n)-\lambda(m+n): m, n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ a finite set.
- Two slopes are "equivalent" if $\{\lambda(n) - \lambda(n') : n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ is a finite set.
- The "positive" slopes have finite $\{ n : \lambda(n) \leq 0\}$.
- ${\bf 1}$ is the identity map ${\bf 1} : n \mapsto n$.

The sum is $\lambda(n) + \lambda'(n)$ and the product is $\lambda(\lambda'(n))$ with $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

This idea is connected with [rotation number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_number) of oriented homomorphisms of the circle.

---

It seems I asked this question identically t years ago.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this "slopes" construction, it's interesting.


Comment: The construction is originally due to Schanuel, not A’Campo. See http://www.maths.mq.edu.au/~street/reals.pdf for some historical remarks.

Comment: They were independent... and the emphases are different. Street/Schnauel are concerned with $\mathbb{R}$ as a logical construction. With A'Campo it seems to come out of geometry & topology. In any case, the integer sequence $\{n \mapsto [αn]\}$ maps to the real number $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.